# How to fill setter method with double[] argument in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arguments, setter

```
public class HealthInsurancePlan {
   
   //variable for setter & getter method
      private double coverage[] = {0.0,0.0};
    
  //setter
      public void setCoverage(double coverage[]){
          this.coverage = coverage;
      }
    
  //getter
      public double[] getCoverage() {
          return coverage;
      }
}
```

1. No why following command doesn't work?
2. What is proper way to fill arguments in the setter method?

   **setCoverage(0.1,0.2);**

Thx.

Comment: I think you want to use: `public void setCoverage(double ... coverage) { ... }` otherwise you'd have to pass an array like this: `setCoverage(new double[]{0.1, 0.2});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java var args so that it accepts variable number of objects and converts it into array of objects. Update your setter as follows:

```
 //setter
 public void setCoverage(double... coverage){
    this.coverage = coverage;
 }
```

and you can just call `setCoverage(0.1,0.2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] a = {2.3, 3.4 , 4.5}; 
HealthInsurancePlan plan = new HealthInsurancePlan();
plan.setCoverage(a);
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
plan.setCoverage(new double[]{2.3, 3.4 , 4.5});
```